# Why disable caching in Chrome to see changes in JS files served from IIS?

Tags: caching, iis, google-chrome-devtools

I spent some time troubleshooting why after setting "Output cache" settings in IIS to "prevent all caching" my JavaScript files were not being reloaded when the page is refreshed. It turned out that I had to disable caching from within the Chrometools network tab. 
 My question is why, as this has never been necessary when using development servers in webpack, gulp, live-server etc unless loading identical resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely because of ETag?
Etag is enabled by default in IIS, but can be turned off.
[This](https://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/iis-8-0-to-use-or-not-to-use-etag-that-is-the-question) article describe the available options

Comment: Thanks for the reading, haven't managed to turn it off but it seems the likely reason